# Copy range of data to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a range of data from one workbook to another. 
I would like to copy any R????????? in Range A3:A999 and it's corresponding version from Range D3:D999 to the next available blank cell in another workbook starting from A2 for the R????????? and D2 for the version number.

This is what i've done so far however i keep getting an error, please help.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

iForm = ("Workbook Location path")

workbooks.Open(iForm).Worksheets("Scheduled Forms").Select

Envrange = "A2:D999"
RowNo = 3

For Each C In workbooks("Daily Release Process.xlsm").Worksheets("Applications").Range(Envrange)

    If C.Value Like "R?????????" Then
    workbooks(iForm).Worksheet("Scheduled Forms").Cells(RowNo, 1).Value = C.Value
    workbooks(iForm).Worksheet("Scheduled Forms").Cells(RowNo, 4).Value = C.Offset(0, 3).Value
    RowNo = RowNo + 1
    End If
Next C

ActiveWorkbook.Save

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic    
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Also, you should put `Option Explicit` at the top off your module to force you to declare variables.

Comment: your range is not that big. look into `AutoFilter` method instead of loop.

Comment: Hi @Kyle i am getting return code "Error 9" at `workbooks(iForm).Worksheet("Scheduled Forms").Cells(RowNo, 1).Value = C.Value`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change `iForm = ("Workbook Location path")` to `iForm = "Workbook Location path"`